# LinguaPlone - link to available translations only

Tags: plone, linguaplone

When using page translations in Plone (v4) with LinguaPlone product (v4.1.2), links to all available languages selected in LinguaPlone settings (`/<PORTAL>/@@language-controlpanel`) are generated. I wonder if it can be configured to link only to available translations for the page (excluding the current language from the links as well). I can't see any relevant options even in `/<PORTAL>/portal_languages/manage_configForm`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you'll have to customize the `plone.app.i18n.locales.languageselector` viewlet and adapt the `available` method to only show those languages where there is a translation for (`context.getTranslations`)

however, this will prevent visitors from switching to another language of the portal in case there is no translation to this language for the current context.

Comment: http://collective-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/i18n/translating_content.html#getting-content-items-in-another-languageHere is the relevant Python bit you need to put into your custom language selector:

Answer (score 1):

You should use  http://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.portlet.lingualinks addon for that.

The global language switcher is in the head to display languages supported and should not be used to navigate between translated content.